# How to check current status of state variables

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, javascript, nodejs

I have deployed my contract locally into Ganache (GUI) and then send/call lot of transactions. After these transactions, now I want to check the current status of all state variables. Is there any way/API to get to know the current status of all state variables of a contract at run time (through program ).

My **solution** toward this is that I am using web3/javascript/nodejs and i have written a program which extract all getter functions from contract ABI. Because, i think these `getters` later will be utilized to know the status of **all** state variables of contract **(I think this logic may not be true to fulfill my objectives**...). I am not sure about it.

**Here is my logic for getters**

```
if(item.type === "function"  && item.stateMutability==='view')
    getters[i].push({
    contract: i,
    func: item.name,
    input: item.inputs
}
```

Later i write a function to to get the status of state variables.

```
async function getStatus(receipt, key, statusArr) {
  var myFunc; 
  var  myContAddr = receipt.contractAddress;
  var myContractAbiDefenition = sources[key].abi;
  var myContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractAbiDefenition, myContAddr);

  for(j=0; j < getters[key].length; j++){
      myFunc = getters[key][j].func;

      try {
        res = await myContractInstance.methods[myFunc](...getters[key][j].input).call({from: account1})  
        console.log("Getter output", res);

      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Getter output: ERROR !");

      }
  }
}
```

**Updated1:**
my actual code of getters for maping of item.input.length > = 0 is as follow. In this code, i just give some dummy values as per input type...

```
if(item.type === "function"  && item.stateMutability==='view'){ 
                      // console.log(item.name)  
                      getterFunctionsNameObject[i].push({
                        contract: i,
                        func: item.name,
                        input: item.inputs.map(({ type }) => {
                          switch(type) {
                            case 'address': {
                              return "0x2cAe18ac37d85CccdE2ebB63D0c391Fe1ac7c36f"
                            } 
                            case 'address[]': {
                              return ['0x2cAe18ac37d85CccdE2ebB63D0c391Fe1ac7c36f', '0xc4ae9984fbbf2416205e81e725e92496ad1eb087']
                            }
                            case 'string': {
                              return 'ABC'
                            }
                            case 'uint8': {
                              return 126
                            }
                            case 'uint256': {
                              return 3546546
                            }
                            case 'uint256[]': {
                              return [546546, 546546]
                            }
                            case 'bool': {
                              return true
                            }
                            case 'bytes': {
                              return "0x3333"
                            }
                            case 'bytes32': {
                              return "0x564b25c8fcd6766f672d43252c8ee2597ad6c7a35315cf13e3b4d0"
                            }
                          }
                        })
                      })

      }
```

Comment: Won't work for array getters (which take `uint index` as input). Won't work for mapping getters either (which take `type key` as input, where `type` is the type of the mapping key).

Comment: For your code to work, you should verify that the number of input arguments is 0 (`item.inputs.length == 0`). Of course, it will not cover all of your contract's getters.

Comment: I know i have cut this mapping to show you clear question .. for simplicity ... but actually i am doing little bit complex ... like this ..input: item.inputs.map(({ type }) => {
                          switch(type) {
           
                            case 'string': {
                              return 'ABC'

Comment: my code is working ... i have already manage how to handle for item.input.lenght>=0 ...

Comment: see my update 1.

Comment: So what's your question then?

Comment: My questions, my approach to get status of state variables is correct ? Is there any better way to get the status of contract , instead of writing getters ?

Comment: It's not gonna be very handy in general. Think about it - you write a dApp which relies on a specific contract or set of contracts. This dApp should sometimes retrieve the value of some specific state-variable. Do you actually want it to loop and fetch all state-variables of all contracts? This could take a relatively long period of time, while your dApp really requires only one of them. You don't want to make your dApp users wait for something which is not really important, right?

Comment: i just have to test it on localhost (ganache) ... i don't need to develop dApp.. i am doing some experiments.. nothing else... thats why i need such kind of stuff... its important for me... i doing research on testing/fuzzing

Comment: Have you tested it for a 2D array, for an array of structures, for a mapping which maps to an array, for a mapping which maps to a structure, for a mapping which maps to an array of structures, for a mapping which maps to a mapping, etc?

Comment: I could not got your point exactly.... I just tested for some variable(shown in above mapping)... Although, some getter function return errors (because i just give dummy values which are not as per contract logic), but i ignored those values... and keep running my transactions ... to get some output...